# Posso colocar um controller dentro de outro no html?

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

vamos supor que meu site feito em AngularJS tenha um `ng-include` de um modal (uma parte da tela que flutua) eu posso definir um controller nesse arquivo HTML para controllar a parte que será incluida mesmo já tendo um controller antes do include?

Comment: Existe algum motivo para fazer isto? Eu já acho que o pessoa exagera na maioria das soluções, isso parece o exagero do exagero.

Comment: Deixar o código todo de uma tela dentro de um único controller não é bom para a legibilidade e manutenção do código. Eu preferiria que cada sub-parte de uma tela tivesse seu próprio controller, assim como os components do Angular 2+

Comment: O que não é bom para a legibilidade é criar um monte de controller. Precisa disso?

Answer (score 0):

Para o modal em específico, você pode usar o angular-ui-bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal), onde possibilita você chamar modais com templates e controllers que desejar.

Para outros templates, que sejam comum na sua aplicação, sugiro a criação de diretivas (com seus templates e controllers) e essas autônomas no seu funcionamento.